# How do I parse JSON with getJSON.

Tags: jquery, ajax

how to read the url http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/21947795900469248/retweeted_by.json using ajax.

I tried this but not working.

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON(url, function() {
      alert(jqxhr);
})
```

I want to read all the screen_name from the json data using the jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `callback=?` at the end.

```
var url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/21947795900469248/retweeted_by.json?callback=?";
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      alert(data[0].screen_name);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read it by passing through the function then you will be able to parse JSON by doing this:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(response) 
{
    for(i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
    {
        alert(response[i].screen_name);
    }
});
```