# How to access nested JSON with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I can't access json nested with jquery.

This is my code:

```
<div class="mypanel"></div>
<script>
$.getJSON('http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cfdUjFmWoO?indent=2', function(data) {
        var text = `Date: ${data.date}<br>
                    Time: ${data.time}<br>
                    Unix time: ${data.milliseconds_since_epoch}`
        $(".mypanel").html(text);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON with getJSON.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001168/how-do-i-parse-json-with-getjson)

Comment: Firstly, `data` in the response is an array so you need to access it by index. Secondly, none of the objects in that array have properties with the names you've used. You can check the response format here: http://jsfiddle.net/mb89fks1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access nested JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463233/how-to-access-nested-json-data)